# Symbolic comparison of integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'd like to prove algorithmically the fact that the integral of $e^{-x^2 - y^2}$ evaluated over a circular disk, ${\cal D}$, is greater than over a square, ${\cal S}$, of the same area *regardless* of the (positive) area.

[image]

The basic comparative relation test would seem to be:

```
Integrate[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0,0}, Sqrt[area/ \[Pi]]]] > 
Integrate[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-Sqrt[area]/2,-Sqrt[area]/2}, {Sqrt[area]/2, Sqrt[area]/2}]]]
```

I want to get a `True` output, but the above does not give it.

I've tried all forms such as `Assuming[area > 0, ....]` and `Assuming[area \[Element] PositiveReals]` and `Reduce` and `Resolve` and `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`, `Subscript[\[ForAll], area > 0]` ... in every combination, without success.  I've also tried `GreaterEqualThan[][]` and related forms, again without success.

I can get the desired result if I assign area to some specific value, but I'd like to prove the relation *regardless* of the particular value.

Comment: it comes down to showing that $\left(1-e^{-\frac{x}{\pi }}\right) -\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)^2>0$ for all positive $x$. But Mathematica can't show this. Plotting this shows this is indeed the case. But Reduce can't do it. In the above $x$ represents the area. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtATd.png) the $erf$ is not easy to work with for reduce. may be you can ask in the math forum.

Comment: Might there be some test involving showing the difference is positive?  Or some series expansion?  Or...?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same. But if you re-write erf function in series, I think it will be worst for Reduce. It also introduces new variation to the problem, which is number of terms? May be if the integral did not have erf in it, Reduce will be able to do it.

Comment: @Nasser there's a relation of the error function to hypergeometrics. Perhaps a help for `Reduce`?

Comment: **(1)** `Integrate[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, r]]` gives $\fbox{$\pi -\pi  e^{-r^2}\text{ if }r>0$}$ **(2)** `Integrate[
 Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, y} \[Element] 
  Rectangle[{(-r Sqrt[\[Pi]])/2, (-r Sqrt[\[Pi]])/2}, {(
    r Sqrt[\[Pi]])/2, (r Sqrt[\[Pi]])/2}]]`  takes 7 minutes to evaluate $\fbox{$\pi  \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi } r}{2}\right)^2\text{ if }\sqrt{\pi } r>0$}$ **(3)** `Resolve[ForAll[r, 
  r > 0, \[Pi] - 
    E^-r^2 \[Pi] > \[Pi] Erf[(Sqrt[\[Pi]] r)/2]^2], PositiveReals]` returns unevaluated.

Comment: @Syed are you sure it was 7 minutes? because after `;// AbsoluteTiming` I get `{0.349316, Null}`

Comment: I am on v12.2 Win7-x64 and the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wnhq.png) shows that the timings are `0.66s` for the first integral and `13.4min` for the second one. Thanks for indicating @bmf. I made a mistake above as I was timing manually with a wall clock.

Comment: @Syed cheers for that. These are the timings with `13.2.0` on a macbook - [**`screenshot`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwfmL.png) Quite off from one version to the other. Anyway, not related to the O.P but I find it bizarre

Comment: Algorithmically it looks tricky. Geometrically, your picture already gives a strong hint (maybe you knew that though). Nice question (and upvoted) in any case.